# Create a rotated clone of a canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I have an extremely simple code, which demonstartes a problem. So, on a page I have this html:

```
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="300" height="300" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;"></canvas>
```

And I have this code:

```
function convertCanvasToImage(canvas) {
    var image = new Image();
    image.src = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
    return image;
}

function convertImageToCanvas(image) {
    var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
    document.body.appendChild(canvas);
    canvas.width = image.width;
    canvas.height = image.height;
    canvas.getContext("2d").drawImage(image, 0, 0);
    return canvas;
}

var canvas1 = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx1 = canvas1.getContext("2d");

ctx1.rotate(-30 * Math.PI / 180);
ctx1.rect(10, 60, 80, 40);
ctx1.stroke(); 

var image = convertCanvasToImage(canvas1);
var canvas2 = convertImageToCanvas(image);
document.body.appendChild(canvas2);

var ctx2 = canvas2.getContext("2d");
ctx2.rotate(30 * Math.PI / 180); // <-- This does not work
```

So, as you can see, I do this. Firstly, I create a canvas, I then rotate it and draw an image, After that I create an image from this canvas and then create a brand new canvas from this image. Finally, I add this canvas to the page and try to rotate it, but it does not work. This code (the last line of the code) has no effect:

```
ctx2.rotate(30 * Math.PI / 180);
```

I tried many other angles, but still see absolutely no effect. What the heck is going on and how can I fix it?

PS. This is the picture of what I have:

[image]

Comment: ctx.rotate does not rotate the canvas. You will have to use css transforms for that. ctx.rotate only rotates the current drawing context, so shapes drawn are drawn in a different angle. What is your goal? It is usually not needed to rotate canvases when writing a game for example.

Comment: According to specs, "The current path, transformation matrix, shadow attributes, global alpha, the clipping region, and global composition operator must not affect the getImageData() and putImageData() methods." This is a major drawback for me that transformation matrix does not affect getImageData and putImageData. So, I wished to mimic the desired behaviour using temporary canvas.

Comment: In the long run, I want to be able to copy some rotated chunk of the canvas. `getImageData` and `putImageData` can not help, because of their limited functionality. This is why I turned to a temporary canvas.

Comment: I suggest you to rotate the drawing context in the convertImageToCanvas function. Please update your question with the desired behavior.

Comment: Thank you, Tamas! I moved rotation inside convertImageToCanvas function and now it works perfectly. You may make a complete answer from your comment, if you wish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use compositing to make a copy of your canvas that contains only the desired rotated rectangle.

1. Create a copy of your main canvas.
2. Fill your rotated rectangle on the copy canvas.
3. Set compositing to `source-atop` which causes any new pixels to display ONLY where the existing pixels are opaque (==only display in your filled rect).
4. Draw the main canvas onto the copy canvas. Only the content from the rotated rectangle will appear -- everything else is transparent.

**Example code and a Demo:**

```js
var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
var cw=canvas.width;
var ch=canvas.height;

var rotationX=0;
var rotationY=0;
var x=10;
var y=60;
var w=80;
var h=40;
var rAngle=-30*Math.PI/180;

var img=new Image();
img.onload=start;
img.src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/139992952/multple/reef.jpg";
function start(){
    cw=canvas.width=img.width;
    ch=canvas.height=img.height;
    ctx.drawImage(img,0,0);
    defineRotatedRect(ctx,rotationX,rotationY,x,y,w,h,rAngle)
    ctx.strokeStyle='red';
    ctx.stroke();
    //
    copyRotatedRectOnly(canvas,rotationX,rotationY,x,y,w,h,rAngle);
}

function copyRotatedRectOnly(canvas,rx,ry,x,y,w,h,rAngle){
    var c=canvas.cloneNode();
    var cctx=c.getContext('2d');
    document.body.appendChild(c);
    defineRotatedRect(cctx,rotationX,rotationY,x,y,w,h,rAngle)
    cctx.fill();
    cctx.globalCompositeOperation='source-atop';
    cctx.drawImage(canvas,0,0);
    return(c);
}

function defineRotatedRect(context,rx,ry,x,y,w,h,rAngle){
    context.translate(rx,ry);
    context.rotate(rAngle);
    context.beginPath();
    context.rect(x,y,w,h);
    context.rotate(-rAngle);
    context.translate(-rotationX,-rotationY);
}
```

```css
body{ background-color:white; }
canvas{border:1px solid red; }
```

```html
<h4>Original Canvas</h4>
<canvas id="canvas" width=512 height=512></canvas>
<h4>Copy containing only the rotated rectangle</h4>
```